# Ionic Cordova build android not working

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I installed ionic and cordova.

When I check my build and emulate IOS is working perfectly but Android is not working.

The message I got is:

```
> cordova build android
Android Studio project detected

Running command: /Users/hongzhiyuan/Desktop/nihao_app/app/niHAO/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /Users/hongzhiyuan/Desktop/nihao_app/app/niHAO

ANDROID_HOME=/Users/hongzhiyuan/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home
studio
(node:28943) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle 
in your path, or install Android Studio
    at Object.module.exports.check_gradle (/Users/hongzhiyuan/Desktop/nihao_app/app/niHAO/platforms/android/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js:150:18)
    at StudioBuilder.prepEnv (/Users/hongzhiyuan/Desktop/nihao_app/app/niHAO/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/StudioBuilder.js:216:23)
    at Api.module.exports.run (/Users/hongzhiyuan/Desktop/nihao_app/app/niHAO/platforms/android/cordova/lib/build.js:154:20)
    at /Users/hongzhiyuan/Desktop/nihao_app/app/niHAO/platforms/android/cordova/Api.js:342:43
    at _fulfilled (/Users/hongzhiyuan/Desktop/nihao_app/app/niHAO/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/hongzhiyuan/Desktop/nihao_app/app/niHAO/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/hongzhiyuan/Desktop/nihao_app/app/niHAO/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
    at /Users/hongzhiyuan/Desktop/nihao_app/app/niHAO/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:624:44
    at runSingle (/Users/hongzhiyuan/Desktop/nihao_app/app/niHAO/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/Users/hongzhiyuan/Desktop/nihao_app/app/niHAO/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
(node:28943) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:28943) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I `rm` android platform and reinstall it but still got the same problem. Any idea how to make it works?

Comment: You should install the gradle for mac and provide the path for gradle like this
`/home/Android/android-studio/gradle/gradle-4.1/bin`

Comment: I did install gradle (using brew install gradle) but not sure about how to put the path

Comment: I don't know how to change the path @MustafaLokhandwala

Comment: Tell me, have you installed the Android Studio?

Comment: Yes I did install Android Studio on my mac

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I did again the `brew install gradle`but this time I opened my vpn. As I am located in China, some codes can not be downloaded without vpn Now it is working